# Passing the correct HTTP status code for a missing resource, before redirecting

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, http-headers

This is a theoretical problem. Let's say I have a public user profile page:

**mypage.com/users/1**

Before the route `/users/{id}` is accessed, I check whether the user (so, the resource) exists. If not, I redirect to homepage:

```
$user = User::find($id);

if (!isset($user)) {
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Now, when a user does not exist, the network tab of Chrome dev tools returns `302 Found` status and then the redirect to homepage takes place.

Is this the correct status to be set? If not, what kind of code should I pass to the redirect to provide information of a missing resource? I don't think it should be `404`, as the route itself might be correct (like `/users/12242343534657`), so - technically - the page might exist. It's just the data that is being requested - doesn't.

What is your experience with this issue?

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All redirects have to use a 3xx status code. [Here's a list of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)

In your case that would probably be 302 (or 301, but this will be permanently cached by the browser which could become a problem)

**However, should you really redirect to the homepage?** I think no. Of course that's just my opinion, but it's really common practice to show a 404 page. (Which doesn't just stand for a wrong route but *Not found* in general)

There are scenarios where redirecting can hurt the user experience. Imagine you manually entered the address of your site like:

```
example.com/usr/lukasgeiter
```

As you might have noticed, I wrote `user` wrong. With a redirect I'd have to type everything again. If you stay on the site and display an error message I can correct my spelling error and load the correct page.

Also it's much more clear to the user what happend that way. Obviously you can put a big link to home on the error page so the user knows what to do next ;)

Comment: That makes sense. Also the user experiece remark is spot on. Thanks!